# How to convert a file that seem binary encoded to utf8 encoding with powershell?

Tags: json, powershell, encoding

**Goal :** I try to convert a file without extension to a readable json encoded in utf8 in powershell.

**Context :** Any pbix file can be "unzipped" by extracting some files in it. Right click + select "Extract to...". It will extract a bunch of files and one folder `Report`. In the `Report` folder there is one file called `Layout`. This file seem to be a json but don't have the json extension. My ultimate goal is to exploit this json, so I try to do it by making a powershell script. But the file is hard to use since I don't really know how to work with this type of file.

**My trials :** First I try to copy the file and change the extension. The json file seem to be okay, but the file doesn't seem to have extension according to Notepad++. And then when I try to convert the content of the file to json it seem not work.

```bash
Copy-Item -Path "\Layout" -Destination "\Layout.json"
Get-Content -Raw "\Layout.json" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Here's the error message :

```
+ ... \Layout.JSON" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Then I try manually to convert it in UTF8 with notepad++ and it worked ! So it's an encoding problem.
So I tried to get the content of the file without extension and THEN I copy the content into a fresh new json file encoded in UTF8.

```bash
$MyPath = "\pbi_json.json"
$MyRawString = Get-Content -Raw "\Layout"
Set-Content -Path $MyPath -Value $MyRawString -Encoding UTF8
```

But it seem to not work well, because the destination file seem parasited with `NUL character` (it's the first character of the ASCII table). Between each character there is a NUL character. And when I check the encoding in Notepad++ it seem to be UTF8BOM instead of UTF8.

So is it possible to get a way to bypass the encoding conversion or a way to solve this conversion problem ? Do forget that the main goal is about creating a json object from the file without extension, so I can take any solution that could help me, the only condition is that this solution shouldn't require an external library.

Comment: That's _some_ of the error message - mind showing us the first line? :) FWIW `Get-Content -Raw "\Layout.json" | ConvertFrom-Json` should work (`Get-Content` is already outputting a string)

Comment: Try `Get-Content -Raw 'Layout' -Encoding Unicode | Set-Content -Path $MyPath -Encoding UTF8`. The output file having embedded `NUL` characters between every other character is a symptom of the input file being encoded in UTF-16 (possibly without BOM, so `Get-Content` couldn't detect it). You may also directly pipe into `ConvertFrom-Json` as Mathias showed.

Comment: Thanks it seem to work but when I try to get the attribute "id" in my json it return nothing ? here's the code : 
`$MyPath = "\pbi_json.json"
$json2 =Get-Content -Raw "\Layout" -Encoding Unicode | Set-Content -Path $MyPath -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host $json2.id`

Comment: @bosskay972 You can remove the `Set-Content` command. It serves no purpose. `$json2 = Get-Content -Raw "\Layout" -Encoding Unicode | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: @zett42 It worked ! Put this one as an answer I will validate it :) !

Comment: You'll get utf16 no bom in windows sometimes.  Or `(get-content file -encoding unicode) | set-content file -encoding unicode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output file having embedded NUL characters between every other character is a symptom of the input file being encoded in UTF-16 (propably without BOM, so `Get-Content` couldn't detect it).

You can force `Get-Content` to use the UTF-16 (Little Endian) encoding by
passing `-Encoding Unicode`:

```sh
$json = Get-Content -Raw "\Layout" -Encoding Unicode | ConvertFrom-Json
```